# How to get value of cell knowing neighboring cell from same row in sql db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns: words and ids. So each row contains a word and number. How i can get value of "id" by knowing only word. In other words how to get word's id using php

I tried to get "word" and "id" column to an array. Then got stuck.

```
$TagList = ('SELECT `word`, `wordid` FROM `^words` WHERE word="abc"');
```

If i get the row in this way how to get "wordid" for "abc"

Comment: My advice is that you should learn and understand sql first.

Comment: @curious_coder good advice, your comment will be more useful if it's about question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM words where word ='abc'";
$result2 = $conn1->query($query);


//fetch the data from the database 
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc() ) {
   echo "id is:".$row['id'];
}
```

where $conn1 is the connection variable

```
$conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a "where condition" to your query

SELECT w.wordid FROM words w WHERE w.word = 'yourword'

Comment: what will be the result?  a string?

Comment: It will be the same type of the column of your table.

Comment: `$TagList = ('SELECT `word`, `wordid` FROM `^words` WHERE word="abc"'); `  so with this i'm getting a row. how to get wordid for "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spoon feeding, I think I should guide you the right way.

You will have to use `SELECT` with `WHERE` clause, and `fetch the rows` and output.

Read `Querying` and `Output query results` from http://codular.com/php-mysqli

You will build a better understanding of how to use SQL from that. The guide is pretty on to the point.